# Vite library mode entry points

Tags: vue.js, vite

My vite config looks like this.
I want to have two entry points, as you can see in build.lib.entry I have the entry for my library, in this case src/main.js, but I would also like to have one entry for my project because I am testing locally.

```
// vite.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.js'),
      name: 'MyLib'
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding the following code inside module.exports, but it didn'T work.

```
entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app.js'),
```

https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode

Comment: if I understood that right, you could just import the main file directly into your ```html``` file:
  ```<script type="module" src="./src/App.vue"></script>```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like vite does not support multiple entries. You can use two vite configuration files.

eg. package.json :

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build --config vite.config.js",
    "build:lib": "vite build --config vite-lib.config.js",
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

In the vite discussions on github it seems you do it with something like this.
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/1736#discussioncomment-413068

```js
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        'entry-point-a': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/entry-point-a.tsx'),
        'entry-point-b': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/entry-point-b.tsx'),
      },
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

When using vite library **you don't need an extra entry point** to test locally. You can just run `npm run dev` to start the dev server serving your `index.html` hat will load `main.js`.

It is also a good idea to move the library files to another folder like `lib` instead of having them in the `src` folder.

You can take a look at the example in the Vite docs: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode

If you want to continue with your setup of using `src/main.js` as the library entry point, you need to update `index.html` to use `src/app.js`.

Comment: I have written a detailed guide on how to use vites library mode for building a React component library here: https://dev.to/receter/how-to-create-a-react-component-library-using-vites-library-mode-4lma